# Local Mail Server Setup

Tags: email, dns, twisted

I am planning a small project to setup a local mail server in addition to already existing mail server on the net. I already have the domain and web presence along with mail server working on the net.

I am thinking of TWISTED to either write this mail server or use an available mail server.
as I will be needing certain customisations to the server.

Challenge I face right now is to how to set this up so that my already existing mailserver on the net and this local server will work together . I am thinking in terms of DNS setup, MX records etc etc..

Can someone guide me a bit on this  and tell me the specifics about how to configure the DNS both local (on the mail server) and my already existing DNS entries at the ISP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like it might be more of a superuser.com question.